# How do I convert a bunch of md files and put them into my page as a prop?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

My ultimate goal here is to get some .md files' contents and return it to my client

I have some file `index.json.ts` that may or may not work, but anyway i cant get the file to run. I'd like to say that this code

```html
export const hydrate = true
export const router = true
export const prerender = true
/**
 * @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').PageLoad}
 */
export async function load({ fetch }) {
    const postsData = await fetch("./index.json.ts")
    const posts = await postsData.json()
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(posts))
}
```

calls the file in the same directory named `index.json.ts` that, in the abridged version, does this

```html
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').RequestHandler} */
export async function GET({ url }) {
    console.log("6rm") // this doesn't run and i want it to 
    const modules: Record<string, () => any> = import.meta.glob("./posts/*.{md,svx,svelte.md}")

    const postPromises = []
   // snip ...
    const pageOfPosts = publishedPosts.slice(0, limit)

    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ body: pageOfPosts }))
}
```

but instead of working I get

```
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Proxy.<anonymous> (file:///home/rlm/Code/ab/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/page/fetch.js:251:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async load (/src/routes/jobs/+page.js:14:19)
```

[if you go here](https://Unexpected%20token%20%3C%20in%20JSON%20at%20position%200%20SyntaxError:%20Unexpected%20token%20%3C%20in%20JSON%20at%20position%200%20%20%20%20%20at%20JSON.parse%20(%3Canonymous%3E)%20%20%20%20%20at%20Proxy.%3Canonymous%3E%20(file:///home/rlm/Code/pro/59/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/page/fetch.js:251:19)%20%20%20%20%20at%20process.processTicksAndRejections%20(node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)%20%20%20%20%20at%20async%20load%20(/src/routes/jobs/+page.js:14:19))  you'll see that it's a "fake" fetch, meaning it kind of behaves like the real fetch api, but isn't the real fetch. my expectation is that it acts like a relative path based on the source file using the fetch.

edit: likely relevant that the action all happens in a directory under `/routes/jobs`, and there's a `/routes/jobs/posts` dir with 3 .md files I want to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch("./index.json.ts")` is incorrect, does not match any route and will thus return a 404, which is why you're getting your error message (a 404 will by default return a blank HTML template and the JSON parser will error out on the opening `<` bracket of the initial `<html>` tag in that template).

You have several issues with your `fetch` call:

- an API endpoint in SvelteKit 1.0+ must be declared in a `+server.js` or `+server.ts` file whose location matches the intended URL path
- extensions (`.js` or `.ts`) must be left off ; this is doubly true of a Typescript file since it would be transpiled into JS first anyway
- while `fetch` URLs *can* be relative, you'd be better off making them absolute to the root of your domain

So from the above points, if your goal is to have an API endpoint that responds to requests made to `/jobs/index.json`, you need to place the `GET` handler inside `/src/routes/jobs/index.json/+server.ts`, and call this API (from your `+page.ts` file) with `const postsData = await fetch('/jobs/index.json')`.

Note that this doesn't intend solve the loading of MD files as I am not completely sure what your intent is regarding that, but it will at least get your API route to run.

Comment: Marked correct because this was *exactly* the logical connection I needed to get unstuck. Thanks Thomas